# Are there ways to utilize remote cluster with multicore (a hybrid tree-like cluster) seamlessly in R?

Tags: r, parallel-processing

Suppose I have a master machine (a weak localhost) and many multicore remote hosts that I can use as a computing cluster. Is there a seamless way to access parallel computing on such? For starter, I'm okay just with `lapply`.

My current thought is to make a socket clusters first then create fork clusters on the intermediate slaves. This creates a nested "hybrid" tree-like cluster, which is interesting but not very seamless.

For example:

```
library(parallel)

hybridParLapply <- function(cl = NULL, X, fun, batches = 1e2, ...) {
  #create chunks of work
  X <- parallel:::splitList(X, batches)
  #execute parallel
  parLapply(cl, X, function(X, fun, ...) {
    library(parallel)
    #a helper function that creates a cluster with "no.core - 2" workers
    do.call(c, parLapply(dplyr::init_cluster(), X, fun, ...))
  }, fun, ...)
}

slaves <- "localhost" # c("some", "slave", "hosts")
cl <- makePSOCKcluster(slaves)
hybridParLapply(cl, 1:1000, sqrt)
#clean up
clusterEvalQ(cl, { dplyr::stop_cluster() })
stopCluster(cl)
```

Relevant code for helpers in `dplyr` https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/blob/master/R/cluster.R

So just wondering if there anything like this already that is mature and seamless. If not, anyone thinks this is interesting enough as a package and/or have any thoughts on the design?

Also this might be considered as a duplicate as:
[Combining Multicore with Snow Cluster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11624460/combining-multicore-with-snow-cluster)
I'm asking more about if there is any packages/sources that I can build upon rather than whether this is possible.